# How to get the entire HTML of an image on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <img src="https://cdn131.picsart.com/271777618047201.jpg?r240x240"
     crossorigin="anonymous" id="image" width="400">
```

Lets imagine, I have a HTML tag as follows:

```
<img src="https://cdn131.picsart.com/271777618047201.jpg?r240x240"id="image" width="400">
```

I can get the image element by `const tag = document.getElementById('image');`. Now, my only ask is, how do I get the html tag as above, on just hovering over the image.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, do you need a reference to the image element, or the markup of the tag?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property of your [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<div>hover me</div>
```

Comment: Nice and elegant answer +1

Comment: This works nicely in StackSnippet, but a real console usually shows a live tree of the element properties. Also, it's depending on where the `e.target` object is used, the output may vary. Maybe `e.target.outerHTML` would be more suitable.

Comment: @Teemu I tried it on picsart, and its working fine there too, if, however, it doesnt work then, I will use your method, thanks.

Comment: I think Teemu was just irritated by your question title. You don't want to get the _html_, you want to get the _element object_ by hover, as you showed in your question. ;) @Khadar111

Comment: ah, yes, I think so too. :)

Comment: @eisbehr I wasn't irritated at all, I just wasn't sure if OP needed an element or the markup. Now it looks like the element reference was needed, and your answer is correct for that.